# Plotting a parametric plot of two functions

Tags: plotting

I have two functions `f1(x)` and `f2(x)`. I want to plot them such that `f1` is on the axis of ordinates and `f2` on the axis of abscissae. Any ideas?

Following example to it:

f1(x)=2x and f2(x)=3x.
The graph should then show a line through the following points: {(0,0),(2,3),(4,6),(6,9),...}

Comment: Are you looking for a way to combine a plot with one that is rotated 90 degrees? Your question and title do not make it clear.

Comment: Dear editor, if you are the OP of this question, please consider registering your account; it'd be more convenient for you and for the rest of us.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Since the question was moved, I though I could not access it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{f2[x],f1[x]},{x, begin,end}]
```

where you have to fill in sensable values for `begin` and `end`.

Example:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[5 x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want this?

```
f1 = Sin;
f2 = Cos;

ParametricPlot[{{f1[x], x}, {x, f2[x]}}, {x, -2 π, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Different rages for `f1` and `f2`:

```
ParametricPlot[
  {{f1[u], u}, {v, f2[v]}},
  {u, 0, 3 π}, {v, -2 π, 2 π},
  Mesh -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Related: [plotting on the y-axis in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6204898/618728)